# In R, find geometric mean of monthly data converted into quarterly data

Tags: r, time-series, data-transformation, geometric-mean

Looking to find **geometric mean** of monthly data that's been converted into quarterly data. I've tried several methods but only provide simple arithmetic  mean as shown below. Thanks.

```
monthly <- ts(mydata,start=c(1960,1),frequency=12)
quarterly <- aggregate(monthly, nfrequency=4,mean) ---need geometric mean
```

This looks promising but unable to mimic the above simple arithmetic mean which considers the monthly to quarterly data transformation:

```
# Function to calculate the geometric mean
geometricMean &lt;- function(array){
 if(!is.numeric(array)){
 stop(&quot;Passed argument must be an array. Consider using sapply for data frames.&quot;)
 }
 if(any(array&lt;0)){
 stop(&quot;All values must be greater than zero. If you are attempting to
 apply this function to rates, convert to +1 format. For example,
 5% becomes 1.05 and -20% becomes .8.&quot;)
 }
 prod(array)^(1/length(array))
}
```

The data has been transformed into percentage change rates (month_12 - month_11 / month_11)

Comment: The transformed data-set has some negative values which are a necessary aspect of my analysis.

Comment: The data set transformation is percent change (positive or negative values),  not explicitly growth rates.

Comment: Please put your comments into the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to is to convert your data into logarithms and then you can compute the geometric mean by taking the exponent of the sum.

I.e., 
$
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{i}       & x_{i+1} & x_{1+2} & \dots & x_{n} \\
\end{bmatrix} \to
\begin{bmatrix}
    Ln [x_{i}] & Ln[x_{i+1}] & Ln[x_{i+2}] & \dots  & Ln[x_{n}] \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

$\text{Geometric mean} +1 = (\prod_i^n (1+x))^{1/n}  = exp\left[ \frac{\sum_i^n ln[x_i]}{ n} \right] = exp\left[\mu_{ln(x)} \right]$

where: $\mu_{ln(x)}$ is the simple arithmetic mean of the logarithm of x.

Comment: It is difficult to interpret the part of your formula that states "$\text{Geometric mean} +1 = (\sum_i^n (1+x))^{1/n}  = $" in any way that makes it correct. What are you trying to assert with that?

Comment: @DavidAddison Taking a log of negative numbers won't work and I have already converted my data into growth rates. I could "add" a constant integer to all my observations and log it but I don't want it to distort my results.

Comment: Rtimeseries, the geometric mean is defined only for non-negative sets of numbers.  By requesting the GM, you were therefore implicitly telling us you have no negative numbers.  It sounds like you are unsure about what you want to do.

Comment: @Rtimeseries. How are you taking growth rates?  Like this: (i.e., $x_t = \frac{x_t}{x_{t-\delta t}} - 1$)? Note that a growth "rate" is only defined for positive x, as is the geometric mean.

Comment: @DavidAddison Provided clarification above.

Comment: I think you might want to look at your order of operations. If meant to show $\frac{\text{month}_n - \text{month}_{n-1}}{\text{month_{n-1}}}$, then you should still be able to add the $+1$, because: $Ln[\frac{x_t}{x_{t-1}}] \equiv Ln(1 + \frac{x_t-x_{t-1}}{x_{t-1}})$

Comment: @Rtimeseries okay. I know you aren’t asking for logs, but I included them as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The geometric mean is undefined when any of the data are negative. This has nothing to do with whether the data are monthly or quarterly, nor with any problems with R or your code.

The solution to this problem seems to be right in the code that you quote, in particular:

> All values must be greater than zero. If you are attempting to
>    apply this function to rates, convert to +1 format. For example,
>    5% becomes 1.05 and -20% becomes .8

Have you tried this?

Comment: Your formula lacks essential terms.  Could it perhaps mean something like "$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{1/n}$"?  If so, please note that the result is not necessarily complex when data values are negative.  What, for instance, does this formula give  for the data $(-1,-1)$? This exposes the subtleties that lead to David Addison's formulation in terms of logarithms and exponentials.